# Hyperlink not working due to zIndex

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have a code which generates a rotating slider, the images shown should be clickable, here is a code snippet from it,

```
 <a href="http://interface.eyecon.ro/demos/images/imagebox/bw1.jpg"
     title="Moon eclipse"
     rel="imagebox" 
     style="top: 20.759592462354455px; left: 222.80008662503428px; width: 52px; height: 26px; z-index: 3; ">
     <img src="./Website_files/th_bw1.jpg" width="100%">
 </a>
```

The links displayed on the slider do not work. As you can see, the link uses zIndex, I am sure that is causing the links not to work but I am unable to decide what should be the done to fix this problem. Please help out. Thanks

Comment: That code alone should work fine. Are there any elements on top of the link that would intercept the click? Or any scripts that would catch the click event?

Comment: what is this? top: "20.759592462354455px; left: 222.80008662503428px;" :O

Comment: It was probably something in em units that got translated that way by the browser.

Comment: @Mr.Alien: Thats for assigning the locations to the images in the rotating bottle.

Comment: How do you know the z-index is the issue? If you remove the z-index, do the links magically start working?

Comment: z-index is not the issue if you see it clearly, he's hyperlinking the image.. why use z-index in that? Do you want <a> to appear on the image?

Comment: @Mr.Alien `<a>` is not a visible elements -- it will never "appear on the image." I think the OP might've been attempting to apply the z-index to the `<img>` instead....

Comment: We need more code to help you. As it stands, the code should work just fine.

Comment: no I meant this <a href="goes somewhere">I want to show this as a link on my slider image</a>

Comment: @Mr.Alien: Yes I want the hyperlink to appear on the image.

Comment: see I told ya, then you need to absolute position that link on the image

Comment: @Mr.Alien: that top and left is the position being specified to subatomic precision by the looks of things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the `DOM element` is absolute to the `parent`, I had the same problem.

Here is an [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/k8Cgm/29/).

**EDIT:**
You should add a class witch would tell that element that it's absolute to the parent and all other elements should be absolute to with `z-index < 3` then link should be click-able.

**EDIT[2]:**
Could you give some jsfiddle example where the code is used so I could change it up so it works!

**EDIT[3]:** Basically even if it puts an object into something, you should be able to assign that `element <a>` is `position: absolute` to the parent, and then the `z-index` property will work.

Comment: The project is divided into multiple files so it would be hard to make a fiddle out of it. I would be thankful if you can download it from [here](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B7z7rCJy9WnKLTFqbjNIb1JWR0E) and have a look. Thanks